# Engame trainer software

Tags: software, endgame

I am learning chess endgames, and I am looking for a software/website, where I can just practice end games with a computer having limited pieces.

For example, if I want to practice queen mate with a lone king. I should have only my queen and my king along with the opponent lone king, and the computer should play the opponent move.

Is there any software or website which have this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

For Android you have the [7-piece chess endgame training](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.convekta.android.lomonosovtb) App, with sets of exercises against Lomonosov tablebases and classified by remaining material per side.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up the position in almost any chess playing program. You would likely get the best competition from programs that have access to the endgame tablebases.

Answer (score 0):

Fritz has a mate training function for this. But you can use any chess engine, with any chess GUI to setup a mate exercise position, and play against the engine. You don't need something special.

[Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/) is the best free engine at the moment.

And depending on your operating system, you can find a GUI to use Stockfish.

Answer (score 0):

[Chessgym](http://www.chessgym.net) has that option.

You can just log in as guest, chose among a number of standard endgames and play it out against tablebases.